# The LINQ expression could not be translated when I try filter my value object property

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I encountered an issue when filtering my Query. this is my query:

```
 var products = _context.Products.Select(x => new GetProductsDto { 
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name.Value,
                Quantity = x.Quantity.Value,
                Brand = x.Brand,
                Displayed = x.Displayed,
                Price = x.Price,
                Category = x.Category.Name.Value
            });

products = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(request.SearchKey));
```

And This is my Product Entity:

```
public class Product{
        public Name Name { get; private set; }
        public Quantity Quantity { get; private set; }
        public string Brand { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public int Price { get; private set; }
        public bool Displayed { get; private set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; private set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; private set; }
}
```

And This My Name ValueObject:

```
public class Name : ValueObject
    {
        public const byte MaxLen = 100;
        public string Value { get; private set; }

        private Name()
        {
        }

        public static Name Create(string name)
        {
            var shopName = new Name();
            if (name.Length > MaxLen)
            {
                shopName.Result.WithError(
                    string.Format(Validations.MaxLenValidation, DataDictionary.ShopName, MaxLen));
                return shopName;
            }
            shopName.Value = name;
            return shopName;
        }
    }
```

And This Is My Product Entity Map to Data Base:

```
internal class ProductEntityMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey( x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Property(x => x.Quantity)
                .HasConversion(x => x.Value, 
                    x => Domain.Aggregates.Products.ValueObjects.Quantity.Create(x));

            builder.Property(x => x.Name)
                .HasConversion(x => x.Value,
                    x => Domain.SharedKernel.Name.Create(x));
        }
    }
```

I think the error is because I'm using 'Name' valueObject In my entity. please help me

Comment: How `Name` is mapped to database?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I've Just Edited Question and Add my Entity Map @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Just for confirmation. Does it work, when you change projection to the following `Name = EF.Property<string>(x, "Name")` ?

Comment: I change that but get this error: 'InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'MyShop.Domain.SharedKernel.Name' and 'System.String'.' @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: It is not new that properties with conversion cannot be used in LINQ queries explicitly. But last chance to make it work without changing Model is gone. Make another or property `string NameDb` - map it to database without conversion. Current `Name` property make `NotMapped` and fill from `NameDb` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I added this line to my ValueObject class, for example in my Name ValueObject class it's like this:

```
public static explicit operator string(Name name) => name.Value;
```

And I changed my query like below:

```
var shops = _context.Shops.AsQueryable();            
if (searchKey is not null)
    shops = shops
        .Where(x => ((string)x.Name).ToLower().Contains(searchKey.ToLower()));
```

And at the end, I checked the SQL Server Profiler Tools to be sure that query execute in server not in client.